# Web crawler not fetching all URLs

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, request, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I coded the following program to fetch all the profile URLs from this search result page https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC=

There are around 18,400+ links to be extracted.

However, when I run the code, it doesn't go beyond URL# 1623 and it stops without giving any error or anything.

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC='

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'}

    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

    for link in soup.select("div#content_findResults div#content_column1 ul li a[href*=MemberProfile]"):
        print 'https://www.ohiobar.org' + link.get("href")
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot comment yet I shall add this as an answer. I Tried running your code on Python-3.4 and this is what I got:

[image: Good Results!]

If it is possible to you maybe just update your python version.

Made a small change on this line:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ohiobar.org/Pages/Find-a-Lawyer.aspx?sFN=&sLN=&sPA=&sCI=&sST=OH&sZC='

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'}

    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    counter = 0

    for link in soup.select("div#content_findResults div#content_column1 ul li a[href*=MemberProfile]"):
        print(counter , ": " , 'https://www.ohiobar.org' , link.get("href"))
        counter += 1
```

Regards,
Alex